# Why does my ViewPager crash?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have 25 pictures in my project and I have a `Button` in my first `Activity`. When click this `Button` I want my app show the first pic of 25, then I want to swipe to change my pics.

This is my `PagerAdapter`:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    Context context;
    private int[] GalImages = new int[] {
            R.drawable.one,
            R.drawable.two,
            R.drawable.three
    };

    ImageAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return GalImages.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_medium);
        imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }
}
```

Then create the xml file and add the `ViewPager` in layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then create main `Activity` and create the instance of `ViewPager`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Everything is good, but when my app arrive to 20th pic of my 25 pics this error appears:

> unfortunately, gallery 3 has stopped

please read here :

i find out some pics are very big so this error appears , when i delete them app is good now....... 
is not anyway else ??
i do not want delete my pics

Comment: LogCat error report will help

Comment: You are using images..may be its OutofMemory..

Comment: Please, format your code